# Isolating a column out of a numpy array using a variable?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I am trying to isolate the last column of a numpy array. However, the function needs to work for arrays of different sizes. When I put it like this:

```
array[:,array_length] 
#array_length is a variable set to the length of one row of the array
```

which seems like it would work, it returns an error telling me that I can't slice with a variable, but only with an integer.

Is there a way to do this with numpy that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What is `array_length`?

Comment: just a variable that is set to the length of one row

Comment: Try `array_length -1`. Python starts counting from 0 up to `n-1`.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you should actually provide the definition of all concerned variables (not a summary of the contents of the variable, but how it is actually set in your program) in your question, in addition to the actual error message you received (including the traceback), rather than a summary of the error message.

Comment: sure. sorry I'm new to this site. the error message is as follows:
"IndexError: each index entry must be either a slice, an integer, Ellipsis, or newaxis"

Comment: I think that gabra has a useable answer below, though. Thanks!

Comment: @OliverChild-Lanning Thank you for the exact error message (which does not say anything about 'slicing with a variable'). Clearly, `array_length` is _not_ "a variable set to the length of one row of the array" (which would be an integer and hence not cause this particular error), which is why I asked to see the definition of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

To access the last column of a numpy array, you can use `-1`

```
last_col = array[:, -1]
```

Or you can also do

```
array_length = len(array[0]) - 1

last_col = array[:, array_length]
```